# Delete from mongoDB by id

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux

I would like to delete an item from my database using the `id` I passed to it, not by the `object ID`. How do I do this?
I have done some reading on `deleteOne` but I'm not quite sure how to go about putting it into use.
Each movie has a button to delete a movie so I need the `id` of each movie to be passed into the remove function. New to MERN stack here.

```json
{
    "_id": "5fa55741aae528142e96c9e6",
    "id": 531219,
    "user": "5fa406cf937ce199eeb176a1",
    "title": "Roald Dahl's The Witches",
    "overview": "large string ... ",
    "poster_path": "/betExZlgK0l7CZ9CsCBVcwO1OjL.jpg",
    "vote_average": "7.1",
    "__v": 0
},
```

My code so far

```js
router.delete('/:id/delete', auth, async  (req, res)=>{
    const movie = await Movie.findByIdAndRemove(req.body.id)

    if(!movie){
        res.send('Movie not found')
    } else{
        movie.remove()
        res.send('movie deleted')
    }

})
```

```js
case REMOVE_MOVIE:
    return{...state, wishlist:state.wishlist.filter(movie => movie.id !== payload)}
```

```js
export const removeMovie = (id) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    await axios.delete(`/wishlist/${id}/delete`)
    dispatch({
      type: REMOVE_MOVIE,
      payload:id
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('unable to delete movie')
    console.error(error)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is `findByIdAndRemove()` looks for the `_id` and you want to use other value to execute the query. So you can use `findOneAndDelete()` function from `Mongoose`.

There are also more functios to do the job as `deleteOne` or `findAndDelete`. But if you want to delete by id I recommend use `findOneAndDelete` because return the deleted document.

Then you have to pass the `id` to query like this:

```js
var deleted = await model.findAndDelete({id: "myID"})
```

Note that `id` is not the same as `_id`.

And that's all...

From documentation, to know how functions works:

[findOneAndDelete()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndDelete/)

> Deletes a single document based on the filter and sort criteria, returning the deleted document.

[deleteOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteOne/)

> Removes a single document from a collection.

And also, if you are using `mongoose` and you want delete by `_id` you can use `findByIdAndDelete()` function instead of `findByIdAndRemove()`.

According to [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndDelete)

> This function differs slightly from Model.findOneAndRemove() in that findOneAndRemove() becomes a MongoDB findAndModify() command, as opposed to a findOneAndDelete() command. For most mongoose use cases, this distinction is purely pedantic. You should use findOneAndDelete() unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: Ok well the issue I'm running into now is that im able to clear the movie from the state, but not from the database. When the app reloads the movie is back again.

Comment: In my answer I used "myID" as string. Do not use double quotes and a number an should work with the original schema.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remedy this issue using the advice above, but I needed to capture and assign the value of the movie being clicked on to the id value passed into findOneAndDelete. I did this by passing in req.params.id. So it was findOneAndDelete({id: req.params.id}). Now everything works as expected. Thanks!